# Add list to Pandas Dateframe, but keep NaNs at the top

Tags: python, pandas

I think this has probably been answered, but I cant find the answer anywhere. It is pretty trivial. How can I add a list to a pandas dataframe as a column, but keep the NaNs at the top?

This is the code i have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
b = [2,3,5,6,4,3,2]
c = [2,3,5,6,4,3]
d = [1,2,3,4]
df["a"] = a
df["b"] = b
df.loc[range(len(c)),'c'] = c
df.loc[range(len(d)),'d'] = d
print(df)
```

which returns this:

```
   a  b    c    d
0  1  2  2.0  1.0
1  2  3  3.0  2.0
2  3  5  5.0  3.0
3  4  6  6.0  4.0
4  5  4  4.0  NaN
5  6  3  3.0  NaN
6  7  2  NaN  NaN
```

However, I would like it to return this instead:

```
  a  b    c    d
0  1  2  NaN  NaN
1  2  3  2.0  NaN
2  3  5  3.0  NaN
3  4  6  5.0  1.0
4  5  4  6.0  2.0
5  6  3  4.0  3.0
6  7  2  3.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Let us try

```
df=df.apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key=pd.notnull))
   a  b    c    d
0  1  2  NaN  NaN
1  2  3  2.0  NaN
2  3  5  3.0  NaN
3  4  6  5.0  1.0
4  5  4  6.0  2.0
5  6  3  4.0  3.0
6  7  2  3.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is with assignment instead of transformation, you can also try with `iloc` with `get_loc` after creating a dictionary (d):

```
d = {'c':c,'d':d}
df = df.reindex(columns=df.columns.union(d.keys(),sort=False))

for k,v in d.items():
    df.iloc[-len(v):,df.columns.get_loc(k)] = v
```

---

```
print(df)


   a  b    c    d
0  1  2  NaN  NaN
1  2  3  2.0  NaN
2  3  5  3.0  NaN
3  4  6  5.0  1.0
4  5  4  6.0  2.0
5  6  3  4.0  3.0
6  7  2  3.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l = df.apply(sorted, key = lambda s: (~np.isnan(s), s), axis = 0)
```

You can sort the dataframe rows using a key argument to keep NaNs first

Answer (score 0):

You may find out how many rows have `NaN` in them (using `s.isna().sum()`) and then do `shift()` to that column by the amount of Nans you have.

Code example on `d` column:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
b = [2,3,5,6,4,3,2]
c = [2,3,5,6,4,3]
d = [1,2,3,4]
df["a"] = a
df["b"] = b
df.loc[range(len(c)),'c'] = c
df.loc[range(len(d)),'d'] = d

df['d'] = df['d'].shift(df['d'].isna().sum())  # example on the 'd' row
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   a  b    c    d
0  1  2  2.0  NaN
1  2  3  3.0  NaN
2  3  5  5.0  NaN
3  4  6  6.0  1.0
4  5  4  4.0  2.0
5  6  3  3.0  3.0
6  7  2  NaN  4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

the way how to do it! just reset index and put na values first.

```
df.reset_index()
df2 = df.sort_values(by =['a','b','c','d'], ascending = False, na_position='first')

#Result
   a  b    c    d
6  7  2  NaN  NaN
5  6  3  3.0  NaN
4  5  4  4.0  NaN
3  4  6  6.0  4.0
2  3  5  5.0  3.0
1  2  3  3.0  2.0
0  1  2  2.0  1.0
```

Comment: The output doesn't match with what OP is looking for. See first row. It should be `0 1 2 NaN NaN`